# Vertically center vertical text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some vertical texts and I can't center then vertically inside their divs.
Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/2657/

See the 3 divs (2 orange and 1 red). The texts inside the divs aren't vertically centered, making the texts leak outside of the divs.

I have tried with `vertical-align: middle` but that won't do anything.

How can I center vertically a vertical text inside a div?

Answer (score 3):

If you text inside the `boxes` can be in a single line than you can use the `line-height` property to align them vertically.

use the `line-height:(height of the container)`

[<kbd>JS Fiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/2664/)

Comment: This kind of works, but when I click on the texts (to expand the divs) the texts move outside the divs. EDIT: Forget about what I said, it works fine with ```float: right;``` :)

Comment: @alexandernst that was an floating issue. Here is an update http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/2662/

Comment: Still kind of buggy. The text from the upper left box is "sin leer" (with a space). If I remove the space, everything shows correctly, but if I add the space, everything breaks.

Comment: add `white-space:nowrap;` to that div

Comment: Yes, now it's perfect :)

Comment: One last question: would that be possible if I didn't know the height of the div?

Comment: yes generally it would be possible using `display:table-cell` but in your current layout `table-cell` can distract your layout.That's why I have not used that here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make texts (multiline texts) vertically center within an unknown height container.

The trick is to use pseudo content with 100% height of container, set `display:inline-block`. And your child element also has to be `display:inline-block;`

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p>texts online line</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>texts will be shown in two lines, lorem ipsum doilor sit amet conse </p>
</div>

<div class="last">
    <p>texts will be shown in three lines, lorem ipsum doilor sit amet conse lorem ipsum dolor sit  </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background:#bababa;
    padding:10px;
    width:260px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}

.last {
    height:200px;
}

div > p {
    margin:0;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100%;
}

div:before {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:0px;
    font:0/0 a;
    margin-left:-4px;
}
```

[<kbd>Fiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/qK7q8/)

**HOW THIS WORKS**

All `display:inline-block` elements in the same siblings will react to `vertical-align` property of CSS; Pseudo element will take 100% height of container and other element will react to that! So you can center vertically at middle or bottom or top even.

Comment: You missed my question. I'm asking for *vertical* texts aligned vertically.

Answer (score 0):

As applied for `#chat` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/hThGb/5521/) it is now easy to do this with flexbox.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `padding` for that three div's